# How to get a response from servlet via ajax?

Tags: ajax, servlets

I'm trying to get a response from servlet via ajax on jQuery, but I get 'error' message. Although 'doGet' part works, 'doPost' part doesn't. Where is the wrong portion in the code?

I appreciate whatever you could inform me. Thank you.

Here is the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({

    type:'POST',
    url:'http://localhost:8080/Ajax/Test',
    dataType:'text',

    success:function(text){
      alert(text);
    },

    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert('error');
    }

});
```

Here is the servlet code:

```
package ajax;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Test() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write("Test_doGet");

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write("Test_doPost");

    }

}
```

Comment: what king of error do you get? StacktTrace? Have you debugged your code? Does the execution reaches the servlet?

Comment: I got an error message on jQuery. (XMLHttpRequest : 0, textStatus : error, errorThrown : undefined) GET works, but POST doesn't. So, I think the execution reaches the servlet. Is a library, such as DWR, necessary in order for ajax to work between jQuery and servlet? I'll try StackTrace.

Comment: Hi  MaVRoSCy, It turned out to be a cross domain problem of XMLHttpRequest. Thanks for your suggestions.